# Request Validation with ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, request-validation

In the past, I've been accustomed to being able to use request validation as a first line of defense for XSS.

However, I don't seem to be able to get the validation to kick in.

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="4.5"/>

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <pages validateRequest="true" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Regardless of this configuration, errors are not thrown and validation is not being run. Is there some other global way to enable/disable validation that I am missing?

Comment: validations are not being hit where: client or server?

Comment: As in request validation is not triggering when a form is posted to the controller.

Comment: So in C# code, not javascript. Ok where is your model, can wee see it?

Comment: To confirm, you're not using any of the newfangled OWIN/Katana stuff, but "classic" IIS-hosted application?

Comment: Also, what kinds of input are you testing with?

Answer (score 1):

There are enhancements added to request validation starting with ASP.NET 4.5 that include deferred ("lazy") validation, the ability to opt-out at the server control level, and the ability to access unvalidated data. In order to leverage these enhancements you will need to ensure that requestValidationMode has been set to **"4.5"**

> web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

from: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ASP.NET_Request_Validation